# model is not working in laravel layout section

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have used this section of code in layout section of my Laravel project:

```
@php

$setting = setting();

@endphp
```

As it is a layout I didn't call this file anywhere but included it many times.

And wherever it is included it is showing me this error.

```
Error
Call to undefined function setting()
```

What went wrong here?
my setting model is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'setting';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
?>
```

also my full layout file is [Here](https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/layouts/front.blade.php)

setting function is defined in the Helper.php file. here it is:

```
<?php

function setting(){
    return \App\Model\Setting::first();
}
?>
```

how can I fix this? TIA

Comment: where is this function `setting` defined?

Comment: Please elaborate more where the setting function is defined. So that we can help you out. thank you.

Comment: setting function is defined in the Helper.php file. I have integrated it in the question

Comment: make sure that file is autoloaded, dump the autoload just in case and please stop putting closing php tags, `?>`, in these files

Comment: No you didnt. its [here](https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/app/Helper.php)

Comment: @lagbox you mean setting function is to be autoloaded?

Comment: the Helper.php file needs to be autoloaded, but seems the composer.json file should be doing that

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use :

```
@php

$setting = setting();

@endphp
```

the `composer` has a `files` key (which is an array of file paths) that you can define inside of `autoload`. so you can add the `path` of the helpers file in the `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

then Run :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

after that in your layout you can use `{{setting()->email}}` or if you use `$setting =setting();` in your layout use `{{$setting->email}}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Manager is properly configured and eloquent booted.

Your [file](https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/app/Helper.php) does not get included via composers autoload. But you actually dont need to load it.

```
@php

$setting = \App\Model\Setting::first();

@endphp
```

Comment: its actually getting error wherever I used setting function. for example, {{setting()->email}} its getting error here also. How can I write in this case?

Comment: `$setting->email` - next time include the error message :)